# why can't I parse JSON without quotes in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

Why can't I parse the JSON object? I need to wrap it in quotes for parse to work.

```
// JSON object
var foo = {"sayHi": {"nl":"hoi", "en":"hello"}};
alert(foo.sayHi.en);

// string       
var foo = '{"sayHi": {"nl":"hoi", "en":"hello"}}';      
alert(JSON.parse(foo).sayHi.nl);
```

edit:

```
// does not work
var foo = {"sayHi": {"nl":"hoi", "en":"hello"}};
alert(JSON.parse(foo).sayHi.nl);
```

Yes, both work, but the first foo doesn't work the with parse. And I like the first foo better, because I don't need to worry about linebreaks, quotes and plus signs.

edit2:

I'm really looking for a nice way to store the JSON in a variable instead of using an ajax call to get it.

Comment: I tried this, and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ceXP9/. What browser did you use.

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is, by definition, a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this `{"sayHi": {"nl":"hoi", "en":"hello"}}` is already js object

and this `'{"sayHi": {"nl":"hoi", "en":"hello"}}'` is just a string, containing whatever, maybe json

Comment: I get it, it doesn't need parse

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "parse the JSON object" (which is not a thing by the way; `JSON` is a notation).  If you want to parse it into an object then congratulations, you're done!  `JSON.parse` takes a string using JSON (the notation) and turns it into an object in JavaScript (but many other languages can also parse JSON and turn it into respective data structures).

Both of your code snippets work as expected, though.